# How to change the value of the publishing status checkbox to false by default?

Tags: forms

[image]

I want that checkbox to be unchecked by default, because currently it's always checked.

And I want this result:

[image]

The structure of my content is as follows:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The question is unclear, because you don't need a form alter hook to set default values for entity fields. This is configuration if it belongs to a bundle since the entire bundle is configuration (see the answer from @leymannx) or if the entity doesn't have bundles this is set in the base field definition which you can alter in a hook if it is not your own entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a form alter this should work:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['#entity_type']) && $form['#entity_type'] == 'MY_ENTITY_TYPE') {
    $form['status']['widget']['value']['#default_value'] = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply edit your content type's default publishing options under [example.com/admin/structure/types/manage/MYCONTENTTYPE](http://example.com/admin/structure/types/manage/MYCONTENTYTPE) (Structure > Content types > MYCONTENTTYPE > Edit).

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: It's a good answer thank you, but in my case the content it has been created generating custom modules so my Content types tab is empty.

Comment: @FranciscoJavierMartnezPrez – OK then please update your question to incorporate this key information and I see that I update my answer.